# asp.net c# Barcode issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]For generating Barcode in asp.net c#, Bitmap object is used that saved the image in jpeg (also checked changing image extension gif and dpi). But the problem is when we print the barcode, barcode quality is not good(it shows the fade print). Although printer "Zebra GK420" quality is good. I did some R&D on the google and used some demo dlls for barcode but barcode quality problem persists. Here is the code snippet and print output document;

```
   Bitmap objBmpImage = new Bitmap(192, 96);
   Font CR10BP = new Font("Courier New", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
   Font TR10NP = new Font("Times New Roman", 10, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
   Font ID12NP = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);

   Graphics objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBmpImage);

   objGraphics.Clear(Color.White);

   objGraphics.DrawString(line1, TR10NP, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10, 2);
   objGraphics.DrawString(line2, TR10NP, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10, 12);
   objGraphics.DrawString(line3, TR10NP, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10, 22);

   objGraphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;

   objGraphics.DrawString(line4, ID12NP, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10, 36);

   objGraphics.Flush();

   return objBmpImage;
```

Comment: Try BMP or PNG, gif and jpeg are lossy formats. Also, try a non-automated method to create and print the barcode to confirm it's not printer settings / the method of printing etc.

Comment: I always thought that Zebra printers accepted an ASCII string for the barcode and generated the barcode image itself.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: I didn't think GIF was lossy (unless you need more than the 256 palette). Though you are write about jpeg and that would certainly introduce artifacts in the image.

Comment: @Chris: You might be right there. GIF is lossy only in terms of colour, so shouldn't effect the outcome since there will only be 2 colours.

Comment: @ChrisBD: You can either print ascii, or give it an image to print. I've used the latter method myself.

Comment: Is the image being scaled at all after generation? Usually if it is being stretched or shrunk or other such transformations then you will end up losing the crispness you started with. Also have you verified the image before sending to the printer (ie just saving it to disc and opening it in your favourite graphics program)?

Comment: As an alternative if you struggle to use an image for this you may be able to use barcode font, this generally requires less code as you just have to convert the barcode number to the characters representing each bar.

Comment: @Purplegoldfish- can you paste here the alternative code if possible

Comment: When i open the saved barcode image in the paint or any other editor. It looks fine but the print quality is not good. Plz guide me through code if possible or let me know if there need to change anything in the mentioned code. thanks

Comment: @zeshanahmad if you google for barcode font you will find some, you need to use a font that works for the barcode format you wish to use. I dont have the code available to paste you.

Comment: @Purplegoldfish- i've google alot and try some other fonts as well as dll but result is poor.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to print barcodes from Zebra printers, you are better off using ZPL to tell it the information about the barcode and having it rendered on the printer.  This is the [ZPL guide](http://www.zebra.com/id/zebra/na/en/documentlibrary/manuals/en/zpl_II_program_guide_en.DownloadFile.File.tmp/P1012728-004.pdf?dvar1=Manual&dvar2=Programming%20Guide%20%28for%20ZPL%20II,%20ZBI%202,%20Set-Get-Do,%20Mirror,%20WML%29%20%28en%29%20&dvar3=GK420d) (only opens in IE for me) for a 420d printer.  Read the guide about the text you send to the printer to get it working.  You can send a text file from the command line to test the printer using standard print commands, so you don't have to continuously recompile as you are learning the language.

Since it looks like you are using a 3of9 font, you will probably use ^B3, which is the 3 of 9 command for ZPL.  Something as simple as this command (an example from the PDF), will render a barcode:

```
^XA
^FO100,100^BY3
^B3N,N,100,Y,N
^FD123ABC^FS
^XZ
```

Comment: Keorner- Please correct me if i m wrong. What i understood is, sending the text file to print after writing these line of code in it. And it will set the zebra printer font etc.

Comment: @zeshanahmad - Correct.  You can print from a command line (to ensure no headers get added by programs like notepad) using print /D:lpt1 filename.txt , where LPT1 is the device for the printer.

Comment: @Keorner- Can't we set these printer properties manully(by right clicking the printer property something like that)? And above script is written in ZP language but how can we do in C#?

Comment: Once you have the script working, you can use standard C# printing code to print the ZPL.  It is just text sent to the printer.

Comment: @Keorner- Can't we set these printer properties manully(by right clicking the printer property something like that)?

Comment: What properties?  It is just text you send to the printer.  How are you printing the other text to the Zebra printer, it should be the exact same code.